# Intel AX201 detected as AC9462. WIFI connectivity problems

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi, firmware

After a fresh ubuntu 20.04 install I'm seeing lower than usual wifi speeds. My laptop is an Acer A515-54g equipped with a WIFI 6 Intel AX201 card, but the system reports it as a AC9462 and seems to use the wrong firmware.

Below is the output of the `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` command:

```
[    6.069779] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.070070] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.072305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    6.072309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.072310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    6.072559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.131350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    6.138864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.139184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.284173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 40:74:e0:90:76:30
[    6.459431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    7.373184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.517950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  299.068231] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 10 old SN frames from c0:3d:d9:4a:24:e8 on queue 4, stopping BA session on TID 4
[  458.067273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 10 old SN frames from c0:3d:d9:4a:24:e8 on queue 5, stopping BA session on TID 0
[  820.641653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 10 old SN frames from c0:3d:d9:4a:24:e8 on queue 5, stopping BA session on TID 0
[  935.614365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 10 old SN frames from c0:3d:d9:4a:24:e8 on queue 7, stopping BA session on TID 3
```

The clearly detects a Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz card.

The `lshw -C network` command tells otherwise

```
*-network                 
   descrição: Interface sem fio
   produto: Wireless-AC 9462
   fabricante: Intel Corporation
   ID físico: 14.3
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:14.3
   nome lógico: wlp0s20f3
   versão: 00
   serial: 40:74:e0:90:76:30
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuração: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic     firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.15.66 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   recursos: irq:16 memória:b4310000-b4313fff
```

And states there is a Wireless-AC 9462 card.

The system loads the `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-*.ucode` firmware while the [intel site](https://www.intel.com.br/content/www/br/pt/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) lists the `iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-*.ucode` as the correct firmware. Also, I get this on the additional drivers app:

[image: Bla]

Ubuntu says my wifi device is not working and the second option "Continue using manually installed driver" doesn't work.

How can I load the proper firmware?

Comment: I don't see any problems. The device is detected and working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Actually no, the proper firmware is loaded. Consult the drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/cfg/22000.c, the IWL_QUZ_A_HR_B_FW_PRE macro. You'll see, that iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0- and iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0- are used for Intel Wireless-AC 9462 indeed.

I also experience the same problem with my MEDION® AKOYA® P17605, Intel® Core™ i7-10510U, Windows 10 Home, 43,9 cm (17,3") FHD Display, MX250, 512 GB PCIe SSD, 1,5 TB HDD, 16 GB RAM, Notebook, using latest 5.6.15 kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Still striving to find a proper solution.

UPDATE 09/2020: With kernel 5.8, problem is still there. I start thinking about giving my laptop back for maintenance...