# Can't use bluetooth headset in HSP/HFP mode - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, acpi

I have a logitech wireless headset that can work in 2 different modes: High fidelity stereo audio (A2DP) without microphone and headset (HSP/HFP) with microfone.

The A2DP mode works, but when I try to switch to HSP/HFP the headset mutes and any background media freezes until I go back to A2DP.

This is the dsmeg output I get when I switch modes:

```
[   82.437350] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0000000FF) is beyond end of object (length 0xF) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[   82.437366] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [GINF]
[   82.437367] Initialized Arguments for Method [GINF]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   82.437368]   Arg0:   00000000bd65d180 <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000FF
[   82.437370]   Arg1:   00000000b898f041 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[   82.437374] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GINF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.437378] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GADR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.437381] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.SGOV due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.437384] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.CGWR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.437387] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.TBFP due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.437390] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMTF.WMTF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441555] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0000000FF) is beyond end of object (length 0xF) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[   82.441571] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [GINF]
[   82.441572] Initialized Arguments for Method [GINF]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   82.441573]   Arg0:   000000007a385f3f <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000FF
[   82.441576]   Arg1:   00000000c7556536 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[   82.441579] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GINF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441583] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GADR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441586] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.SGOV due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441589] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.CGWR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441592] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.TBFP due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   82.441595] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMTF.WMTF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   92.294393] input: Logitech Wireless Headset (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input41
```

PC specs are

Acer A515-54g (Bios v1.17 - lastest)

WIFI: Intel WIFI6 AX201

Intel Core i5 10210u

Dual boot with windows 10 (fast boot disabled)

EDIT:

ACPI errors can be caused by driver problems. The intel AX201 card is a very new one and the system does not detect it properly (as I asked in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232224/intel-ax201-detected-as-ac9462-wifi-connectivity-problems)). May be the issues are related somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been experiencing this issue as well. There is a confirmed bug for pulseaudio and bluez. Please report that it affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1878194

Comment: As of December 16th 2020, the issue is fixed in ubuntu 20.04 when updated to kernel 5.4.0-58.

Comment: Facing this issuein Ubuntu 16.04. Is it resolved yet?

Comment: @DiegoBlanco it definitely is NOT fixed for me, 20.04 with kernel 5.8.0-48

Comment: In my case pavucontrol shows all profiles as "unavailable" except for a2dp sink

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue just after moving from 19.10 to 20.04.

When the bluetooth headset is connected it is automatically configured as HSP/HSP but it does not work with this configuration (in 19.10 it did).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my Bluetooth headset work in HSP mode, which means the microphone works too.

### 1st step: be sure your bluetooth firmware

While when I was executing the command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`
I had a similar message of this:

> bluetooth hci1: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd failed with error -2

and after installing the [broadcom-bt-firmware](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware#installation) the same command return

> [   21.883358] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd' Patch

### 2nd step: edit /etc/pulse/default.pa

and comment the ifexist and endif around module-bluetooth- so the policy and the discover load automatically

```
### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
#.endif

#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

### 3rd step: purge and reinstall pulse

I followed [this awsner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)
`sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install pulseaudio`
and be sure in `/etc/pulse/client.conf` your `autospawn = yes`
than `reboot`

Comment: Without needing to install any `ofono` packages?

Comment: @akaihola yes, without ofono