# lspci detects wrong network adapter 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi, lspci

## Issue:

Ubuntu 20.04 won't detect Bluetooth card and I believe it may be because the wrong driver is being used. 
I have a HP Spectre 360 laptop that uses an Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201 network card (it has Bluetooth integrated).

---

## Analysis

***dmesg*** command indeed detects this device (as well as the device manager in windows) 
`[    2.403441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354`

However ***lspci*** command detects a different Intel network device (which uses a different iwlwifi driver [version](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)) `0:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]`

---

## Supporting information

dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.258249] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.290882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 58.3.35.22
[    2.290886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.290888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.291196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 50.3e391d3e.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.403441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    2.412010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.412482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.642481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 28:7f:cf:58:44:a4
[    2.850831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    4.107788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.260625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

lspci output:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

lsusb output:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bb Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`$ dmesg | grep -i blue` returns nothing

`$ ls /sys/bus/sdio/devices` returns nothing

rfkill output:

```
$ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Comment: Wifi devices may be on one of several possible busses: pci, usb, or sdio.  lspci will show those devices on the pci bus, lsusb those on the usb bus, and ls /sys/bus/sdio/devices for those on the sdio bus.

Comment: @ubfan1 would the Bluetooth device be found in the same buses?

Comment: I suspect that the bluetooth device may be found in `lsusb` Please edit your question to show the result. Also, please show the result of: `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @chili555 please find attached the updates. I’m also wondering if it is possible that the device remains taken by Windows 10 even if I boot in Ubuntu that that is why it may not be detected? (I’m running in an EFI dual boot system)

Comment: "if it is possible that the device remains taken by Windows 10 even if I boot in Ubuntu that that is why it may not be detected?" Possibly! Plase check here:  https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Typically, this affects the wifi only, not bluetooth, but I suggest that you experimentally disable fast boot in Windows to find out. Does it change the remarkably sparse `lsusb`?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232224/intel-ax201-detected-as-ac9462-wifi-connectivity-problems